# Marionette onShow not firing after rerender region view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a region, and I need to execute some code once the view is rendered. So the first time I call `myRegion.show(myView)`The code that goes inside `onShow` in `myView` does the work.

The same piece of code doesn't work `onRender` or at `initialize`. The problem comes, when after a change in `myView` I call `this.render()` to reflect the changes. This time, "onShow" is not firing.

I think that I can trigger an event from the view, catch it at the parent view and call again to myRegion.show(myView). But it looks like a tricky solution, and I don't know if there could be a better way to manage this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onShow` callback is called only once when you insert your view into the region.

I think in your case you should use `onDomRefresh`. Marionette calls it when view is showed into region and when it is re-rendered (but only when it is showed already). So you can make all your DOM dependent code in it.

You can read more in docs:  https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-domrefresh--ondomrefresh-event